# If the OP knows their code is wrong but truly has no access to the problem details, can asking for the corner case that breaks their code be on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope, minimal-reproducible-example

I've seen a few questions recently where the OP has written what they feel is a complete implementation of their desired code, has learned that it is wrong for at least one input, but does not know what inputs it's wrong for, or why.

Is this really on- or off-topic? A pseudo-question example:

> I'm trying to achieve X, Y, Z.
>
> I have learned from an automated checker that there is at least one case where my code gives the wrong answer. Can you find me an example that breaks my code ***[AND/OR]*** what's wrong with my code?
>
> Here's my code:
>
> ```
> blah
> blah
> blah
> ```

These seem to run afoul of the "no [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)" close reason, because they don't describe the problem in detail. However, that's because the OP truly doesn't know the details of the problem (unlike, for example, OPs who refuse to copy/paste stack traces for our benefit because *they* don't understand how to read them). What if they have a good, mathematical description of what the program is supposed to do? Can that description, plus "someone[/thing] I trust says there exists a counter-example", fulfill the problem description requirement?

I think this is another way of looking at it: is asking for counter-examples/corner cases that break code on-topic, if the code is reasonably short, the code's requirements are well-described, and the OP is confident (not just guessing or wondering) that there is such a counter-example to be found? I expect in many of those cases someone in the community will spot a counter-example, and be able to answer the question.

Comment: That sounds so much like a given assignment for school.... All in all, it does feel off topic, as this would fall in the code-review/debugging.... If its an automated checker, there HAS to be a way to know the faulty input...

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking us for? Should these questions be closed? Should we answer them? The answer to each are the inverse of the other.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker I guess I was thinking "is it on- or off-topic" means the same thing as "should we close it". Is there a subtle difference, or is there some way I could make my question clearer?

Comment: I'm aware that "answerable" and "on-topic" are different.

Comment: We performs miracles every day, questions very often have irrelevant snippets.  But clearly the impossible takes too much work to be practical and pursing it gets to be a waste of time that could be better spent on Q+A that is useful to more than one person.  There is no "too localized" close reason anymore so you can't indicate the real problem or say what you think.  You'll have to wing it, "too broad" is fine, "off topic + no mcve" is fine.

Answer (score 1):

A problem that the asker does not know how to reproduce does not fully meet the recommendation of an MCVE as [written](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

But the question as described appears to deal with "Correctness in unanticipated cases". Such questions about otherwise working code appear to lie within the [scope of Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). So if a question like this does get put on hold for being unclear, where the unclarity arises from lacking an MCVE, consider cleaning it up in preparation for a migration there.

Comment: For the record, an MCVE is not a requirement.  Lack of MCVE is not a close reason by itself, so your statement about "put on hold for lacking an MCVE" is not accurate.  An MCVE is recommended as it can help make a question clearer or more easily answerable, and the process of creating it can sometimes solve the problem for the OP.

Comment: @psubsee2003 Touché. The close reason is "unclear", and I've clarified my answer.